# Why do I get Referenced bean nullChannel not found?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I usually get a warning about *nullChannel* not being defined in STS `Problems` view:

```
 Referenced bean 'nullChannel' not found
```

But then if I add a declaration in context file, like `<int:channel id="nullChannel" />` or `<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="nullChannel">`, I get an:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The bean name 'nullChannel' is reserved.
```

I guess that's a warning I can safely ignore, but I usually try to zero out warnings, so is there something I'm missing?

---

### UPDATE

These are the portions involved with the warning, removing them made it disappear:

```xml
<int:header-value-router input-channel="listOfMaps" header-name="transaction_type" resolution-required="false" default-output-channel="nullChannel">
    <int:mapping value="52" channel="requests52ListOfMaps"/>
</int:header-value-router>
```

```xml
<int:service-activator input-channel="httpRequestsSendsChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="conversionController" method="enable52Delivery" />
```

```xml
<int:service-activator input-channel="httpRequestsDeletesChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" ref="inspector" method="inspect" />
```

Comment: What version of STS are you using? Where are you referencing `nullChannel`?

Comment: @GaryRussell STS 3.9.3, Spring Integration 5.0.4 and I'm referencing it in a custom _service-activator- and in a mapping of a _header-value-router_.

Comment: I need to see your actual config - can you edit the question? I don't see the error/warning (although I have 3.9.4).

Comment: @GaryRussell My configuration is a bit complex, but I found the piece s that make the warning appear (please see my update). Is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why it was ok for me last week (probably pilot error) but I get it now with

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="nullChannel" expression="foo" />
```

and, if I flip the in/out channels, the warning changes to `errorChannel` - the reason we don't get a warning for the input channel is because STS presumably knows that we will create input channels on the fly if needed.

I guess STS just doesn't know about these implicit beans.

I'll ask the STS guys if we can come up with a way to give them a list of implicit beans to suppress these warnings.

If that's not possible, we could consider relaxing the rule preventing the adding of a custom `nullChannel` bean.

Comment: [Issue opened](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/280).